# Particle P0 (C++) no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ClassA (*)()' to 'ClassA*'

Tags: c++, class, pointers, arduino, embedded

I currently have two classes in some code I'm working on for a Particle P0, say ClassA and ClassB. The firmware is very similar to that of Arduino. I would like to be able to instantiate ClassA and ClassB in my main code, but then access ClassA from ClassB. See example mainline below.

```
ClassA cA;
ClassB cB(&cA);
void setup(){}
void loop(){}
```

Here is what I have in ClassA:

```
#ifndef _ClassA_H
#define _ClassA_H
#include "application.h"

class ClassA{
public:
   ClassA();
   void test(void){q++};
private:
   int q;
};
#endif
```

And in ClassB:

```
#ifndef _ClassB_H
#define _ClassB_H
#include "application.h"
#include "ClassA.h"

class ClassB{
public:
   ClassB(ClassA * classA);
private:
   int i = 0;
};
#endif
```

The goal is to have a method in ClassB that can access information in ClassA. For example...

```
_classA->test();
```

In my use case, I am attempting to store cloud information within ClassA and ClassB holds a series of callbacks for timers. This way, after certain timer callbacks in ClassB, I can check if there are any status updates from the cloud in ClassA such as user input.

However, I am getting multiple errors when attempting to do this.

```
ClassB.h:9:3: note: ClassB::ClassB(ClassA*)
   ClassB(ClassA * classA);
   ^
ClassB.h:9:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ClassA (*)()' to 'ClassA*'
ClassB.h:7:7: note: constexpr ClassB::ClassB(const ClassB&)
 class ClassB{
       ^
ClassB.h:7:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ClassA (*)()' to 'const ClassB&'
ClassB.h:7:7: note: constexpr ClassB::ClassB(ClassB&&)
ClassB.h:7:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ClassA (*)()' to 'ClassB&&'
make[1]: *** [../build/target/user/platform-6TestCode.o] Error 1
make: *** [user] Error 2
```

I have had some success by changing ClassB to the following:

```
class ClassB{
public:
   ClassB();
private:
   int i = 0;
   ClassA * classA;
};
```

My issue with this is I have a pointer to classA but have no way to access memory allocated to cA (instantiated in main).

I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: _I now have another instantiation of ClassA_ - a pointer to an instance is not _another instantiation_ and through it you can refer to `cA`. Anyway, post a minimal example to reproduce the error, otherwise it's difficult to say what's wrong exactly.

Comment: I see, thanks for the fast response. Could you clarify, how would I access `cA` from `ClassA * classA;`? Thanks!

Comment: What's `_classA` and why would you initialize it by calling its constructor with a pointer? Your example doesn't make sense.

Comment: `_classA` could be removed. I would like to be able to call a constructor with a pointer to the instantiation of a class. This works for me when sending the address of the Serial or SPI class. See this [adafruit example](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_GPS/blob/master/examples/echo/echo.pde). There they pass the address of the Serial class into a class used for GPS interface. Would like to do a similar thing with ClassA and ClassB.

Comment: Why does have to be a pointer. Cant the instance be built by class B?

Comment: Perhaps it could be build in `ClassB`. Would I just put `ClassA classA;` in the constructor of `ClassB`? Additionally, would I be able to access classA from the mainline?

Comment: The `'ClassA (*)()'` in the message indicates that you have a function returning `ClassA`. Your real code doesn't have `ClassA cA();` in the main, does it?

Comment: @BoPersson you were exactly right! I must have had multiple arguments in `ClassA cA(something)` but forgot to delete the `()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the instantiation of `ClassA cA;` I accidently wrote that as `ClassA cA();`

Thank you, everyone for your input.